# Load test tool that handles multiple urls and headers

Tags: performance, jmeter

I'm looking for a load test tool for macOS that can handle different URL's and set different Auth headers for requests. I've looked at both **jmeter** and **ab**, which works fine for a single url with a single auth header, but I'd really like to simulate more real load by sending requests from many different users and there by making it harder for the database and caching layers.

**SuperBenchmarker** seems to handle these cases, but it doesn't really work well on macOs at least (haven't tried Windows version)

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize the headers by reading them through a data file. Have a look at the following link for example which uses a csv file to read the values and which you can inject into your request

https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG

Answer (score 0):

If [SuperBenchmarker](https://github.com/aliostad/SuperBenchmarker)  suits your needs be aware that you can run it on a Mac, just make sure to install [.NET Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) first

[image]

However both [`ab`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) and `SuperBenchmarker` are "basic" tools which can only "hammer" one or several endpoints while well-behaved performance test must be a little bit more intelligent.

Modern browsers are large and complex beasts which not only send [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and render the responses, they do a lot of extra activities like:

- downloading embedded resources (images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc.)
- having local [in-memory and disk caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) in order to avoid duplicate requests for "heavy" content like images on subsequent requests
- establishing and maintaining sessions using [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- parsing JavaScript and executing [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) calls

So if you're considering JMeter make sure to follow recommendations from [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article, this will allow you to produce more realistic network footprint and this is something you should be doing to get the answers to questions like "how many users does my application support" or "what is the maximum number of hits per second which my application is capable of serving"